# c# code to access all the controls of a html table row

Tags: c#, asp.net

what i am doing is to find the checkbox control in a html table(id=tblorder) which is in the div(id=test1) and i am working in the content page and what i want is to access all the controls(other textboxes) which lies in the same row of the html table.all the code that i have tried is in coments but none of them works

```
<div id="test1" runat="server">
      <table id="tblorder" align="center" class="auto-style3" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style9">
                         <asp:Label ID="label11" runat="server" Text="Order Number : "></asp:Label>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblorderno" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter item description"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td class="auto-style8"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Amount"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style12">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCoat" Text="Coat" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style13">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc1" runat="server" Width="339px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style14"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt1"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPant" Text="Pant" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc2"  runat="server" Width="337px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style15"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt2"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShirt" Text="Shirt" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc3"  runat="server" Width="338px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style15"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt3"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chksherwani" Text="Serwani" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc4"   runat="server" Width="335px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style15"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt4"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmodijacket" Text="Modijacket" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc5"  runat="server" Width="336px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style15"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt5"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               </div>
```

C#

```
foreach (Control ctrlChk in test1.Controls)
{
    if (ctrlChk is CheckBox)
    {
        string tt=((CheckBox)ctrlChk).Text;
        if (lstItemsCount.Any(obj => obj.Contains(tt)))
        {
            //TableRow tr = (TableRow)ctrlChk.NamingContainer;
            //string selRowIndex = (Table)(ctrlChk.Parent.ID;
            //CheckBox objttl = (CheckBox)ctrlChk.Parent.NamingContainer;
            //  var re= (CheckBox)ctrlChk.NamingContainer;

            ((CheckBox)ctrlChk).Checked = true;
            lstItemsCount.Remove(tt);
            i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you do after you find the controls? You should be able to access the checkbox via ID's and toggle their checked values from code behind. You can do whatever in event when OnCheckChange event.

Comment: as you can see i am matching lstitemcount to the checkbox text when it matches the coresponding data from the database is to be inserted in the textbox of same row

Answer (score 0):

all i did is defining the parent of the TextBox using this code :

```
            Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBoxID");
        if (myControl1 != null)
        {
            // Get control's parent.
            Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
            Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Control not found");
        }
```

then  :

```
foreach (Control c in ControlParent.Controls)
        {
            if(c is TextBox)
            {
                (c as TextBox).Text = "";
                
            }
        }
```